# Flask AttributeError: can't set attribute

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am making a project on python flask when I created a database with sqlite the database is created and the value is inserted in that but when I restarted my project and try to insert the values in the database through python console like

```
from app import db
from app import Credentials as C
c= C(fname="John", lname="Doe", username="johndoe", email="john@doe.com", password="11111111")
```

I got an error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\FlaskProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\state.py", line 417, in _initialize_instance
    manager.dispatch.init_failure(self, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\FlaskProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\FlaskProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 249, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\FlaskProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\state.py", line 414, in _initialize_instance
    return manager.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\FlaskProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\base.py", line 700, in _declarative_constructor
    setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Help me to solve the error I am using all the latest versions of libraries

Here is my model definition:

```
class Credentials(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fname = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    lname = db.Column(db.String(32))
    username = db.Column(db.String(16), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    @property
    def password(self):
        raise AttributeError('password is not a readable attribute')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Users('{self.fname}','{self.email}','{self.username}')"
```

Comment: The signup form and route have nothing to do with the error you see in the console, that only uses `Credentials`, which you haven't shared.

Comment: Also, please don't manually indent your code to make it look 'okay' in a post here. Paste your code, select the block of lines you want to format as 'code', and then use the `{}` button on the editor toolbar to format those lines in one step.

Comment: Sorry for that as I am new here, I'll take care of that next time.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is caused by the `password` property definition:

```
@property
def password(self):
    raise AttributeError('password is not a readable attribute')
```

This *replaced* the earlier definition for the name `password` with a property object without a setter. You can reproduce the issue with

```
>>> class Foo:
...     @property
...     def bar(self):
...         raise AttributeError('bar is not a readable attribute')
...
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.bar = 'new value'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Properties do not have setters unless you explicitly give it one, and properties are just more objects in the class namespace, you can't use the same name for a column definition and the property.

You could just rename the column to `_password`, for example, but there is a bigger issue here: ***You should never store user passwords in your database***.

Instead, you should store password *hashes*, cryptographically generated unique strings that can only be reproduced when, in the future, your program is presented with the same password. That way you can *verify* that someone still knows the right password without giving hackers access to the passwords if they manage to steal your database.

***It is very important that you never give hackers access to passwords***. See [this analysis of a breach of security at Adobe](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/04/anatomy-of-a-password-disaster-adobes-giant-sized-cryptographic-blunder/) for why you would never want to be in the same situation. My account was compromised in that hack too, but only because I use unique passwords per site have hackers not been able to re-use my account information to access other sites.

See [this guide](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/users.html#storing-passwords) for a good overview of what you should be doing instead. Flask comes with the right tools to do this for you.

Here it should be sufficient to use the [`werkzeug.security` package](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/utils/#module-werkzeug.security):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

class Credentials(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fname = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    lname = db.Column(db.String(32))
    username = db.Column(db.String(16), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    _password_hash = db.Column('password', db.String(100))

    @hybrid_property
    def password(self):
        return self._password_hash

    @password.setter
    def _set_password(self, plaintext):
        self._password_hash = generate_password_hash(plaintext)

    def validate_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self._password_hash, password)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Users('{self.fname}', '{self.email}', '{self.username}')"
```

I used the [SQLAlchemy hybrid property object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) to handle the `password` attribute here. Note that the *column* is stored in `_password` (but the database column is still called `password`), and that the value is automatically hashed when you set it.

You can then validate passwords against the database-stored hash with the `check_password()` method.

The `werkzeug.security` implementation guards against timing attacks (where an attacker can work out if they are close to a proper password by measuring how long it takes your server to validate passwords), but is weaker in that it supports legacy protocols. Other packages such as Flask-BCrypt let you configure stronger policies.

Answer (score 2):

I have also encountered the same issue today. Most likely it is an issue with `SQLAlchemy` which is a dependancy of `flask-sqlalchemy`. I compared the version I used in a recent project and the current version and found out there is an update to `SQLAlchemy==1.4.0`.

To check the version, I did:

```py
$ pip3 freeze
```

To revert to the previous version, I first uninstalled the current `SQLAlchemy==1.4.0` and reinstalled the previous version `SQLAlchemy==1.3.23`

```py
$ pip3 uninstall SQLAlchemy==1.4.0 # my current version
$ pip3 install SQLAlchemy==1.3.23 # previous working version
```

Update your requirements:

```py
$ pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

@Martijn Pieters is right to some extend (about establishing a setter to set value) but his approach will throw an error due to different attribute name. See below for details.

Whether you use `@hybrid_property` decorator or a native python object's `@property` decorator you must retain same attribute name used in property defination for setter or getter methods.

Here in your case `def _set_password()` should be `def password()`. Your code should look like this:

```
 @hybrid_property
 def password(self):
     return self._password_hash

 @password.setter
 def password(self, plaintext):
     self._password_hash = generate_password_hash(plaintext)
```

Detail Explanation: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4332